# Can I send a form action to php file outside public folder?

Tags: php, html, forms

Following [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) to create a safe login system, I came to this problem.

In Part 7 of 8: Create HTML Pages, section 1 Create the login form (index.php), it uses:

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
```

Although earlier on the tutorial it states (Part 3 of 8, section 1, first paragraph):

> In a production environment you'll probably want to locate this file
>   and all your other include files, outside of the web server's document
>   root. If you do that, and we strongly suggest that you do, you will
>   need to alter your include or require statements as necessary, so that
>   the application can find the include files.

So my includes folder is not inside /var/www/html/mysite/ or /var/www/html/, but in /var/www/, and my form became:

```
<form action="../../includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
```

(which works for the php includes). But this one don't work, I get this error:

> http://localhost/includes/process_login.php The requested URL
>   /includes/process_login.php was not found on this server.

Why is it acting as if my includes was inside /var/www/html/ ?
I checked all my /var/www/ folders using

```
grep -rnw . -e 'process_login.php'
```

and this is the only occurrence of that string (with the ../../). What am I missing?

Comment: you can *include* the includefile in a file which can be reached through webserver ... see *include()* *require()* *require_once()* *include_once()*

Comment: @donald123, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyway, I still want to understand why this is needed.

You have to understand that the html file is "executed" on the client side, meaning that if you link to something in the html file that is higher than the public folder (which the client perceives as root), the client cant reach it, as it is not available to the client. The client just cant send a request to a folder which is not made available to it by the web server.

A php script however is executed on the server side, meaning it can access folders that are higher than the html perceived root.

Basically: html thinks the root directory is the public folder, php thinks the root directory is the actual server root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by including a file that just includes another, being the first in a public folder and the second in a hidden folder.

The form:

```
<form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
```

First file (public_folder/mysite/process_login.php):

```
<?php
include '../../includes/process_login.php';
```

Second file (../../includes/process_login.php):

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $pwd, $conn) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../coisas/protected_page.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../coisas/index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Anyway, I still want to understand why this is needed.

Comment: Just for all non-unix users: the `..` in a path is the parent folder.